# Zoom the custom view from android viewpager with left and right padding

Tags: android, android-viewpager, zooming, pinchzoom, gesturedetector

I've a Viewpager with left and right padding (*for showing the preview of left and right child views of pager*).

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/reader_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp"
        android:background="#000000"/>
```

The viewpager holds set of zoomable views ([Link to ZoomLayout](https://github.com/shopgun/zoomlayout/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/shopgun/android/zoomlayout/ZoomLayout.java)) which helps to zoom my custom view individually.
**But when I zoom (pinch-to-zoom) the custom view, this zoomed view is getting cut from left and right due to viewpager padding.**

Is there anyway to zoom the child view individually without getting cut or hidden due to the left and right protruding views of viewpager? Need to pinch-to-zoom over or under the left & right protruding views.

Tried adding **clipToPadding=false**, but the zoomed view is cut at one side.